# How to query for records that don't have a particular field value?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a custom object `Customer__c` that stores contact and address information (along with other information).

Every time a contact is created without inserting an address, a record of `Customer__c` is created with `Contact_ID__c = 'contacts id'` and `type = 'Contact'`.

Every time a contact is created with address, two records of `Customer__c` are created. One with `type = 'Contact'` and another with `type = 'Address'`. Both have `Contact_ID__c = 'contacts id'`

If I am given a set of `Contact_ID__c`, how can I query for records of `Customer__c` that only have a record of `type = 'Contact'` and don't have a record of `type = 'Address'`? In other words, I want to get the contacts in the set that don't have an address.

Is it possible?
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Phil's approach, but I feel it could probably be achieved with an SOQL subquery something like this :

```sql
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Contact__c 
WHERE Id NOT IN (
  SELECT Contact_Id__c 
  FROM Customer__c 
  WHERE Type__c = 'Address'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone may have a better approach, but one option I can think of is to query those that DO have an address and remove those from the set of initial contacts, something like (assuming you can do this via Apex in your use case):

```
Set<Id> contactIds = ...;
List<Customer__c> withAddresses = [
    SELECT Contact_ID__c
        FROM Customer__c
        WHERE Contact_ID__c IN :contactIds
            AND Type__c = 'Address'
];

Set<Id> withAddressIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Customer__c customer : withAddresses) {
    withAddressIds.add(customer.Contact_ID__c);
}

Set<Id> withoutAddressIds = new Set<Id>(contactIds);
withoutAddressIds.removeAll(withAddressIds);
```

At the end of this, the `withoutAddressIds` set contains IDs from those initial contacts that don't have an address.